# Custom radio button id in Twig

Tags: symfony, radio-button, twig

Code of rendered Twigs radio button set form usually looks like...

This:

```
 {{ form_widget(formTitle.radioSet)  }}
```

To this...

```
<input type="radio" id="formTitle_radioSet_0" name="formTitle[radioSet]" value="fooValue">
<input type="radio" id="formTitle_radioSet_1" name="formTitle[radioSet]" value="booValue">
```

... and a few more rows like this

I want to make it work with JS easier. Is it possible to render customized radio buttons with IDs reffered to the value of radio and my own preferences like this??

```
<input type="radio" id="radioSet_fooValue" name="formTitle[radioSet]"  value="fooValue">
<input type="radio" id="radioSet_booValue" name="formTitle[radioSet]"  value="fooValue">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [custom form rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

You will just need to customize the `widget_radio` block using one of the techniques described in that cookbook entry

Comment: Noticed this article while was surfing for solution... looks terrifying, I hoped, there is a easier way to do this) But thanks anyway.

Comment: It´s easier than what it looks

Answer (score 2):

After about half an hour of exploring article recommended by [Carlos Granados](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1557651/carlos-granados) got a solution. The target is to override twigs template of renderind radio inputs.

In a few words, code below, pasted at the beginning of your web page template will override ALL radio's render the way it described in question.

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
{%- block radio_widget -%}
<input type="radio" name="{{ full_name }}" id="radio_{{ value }}" value="{{ value }}"{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
{%- endblock radio_widget -%}
```